# Gitlab CI fails during npm install

Tags: docker, npm, gitlab-ci

Hello I have a exit code 1 error during npm install in my docker container, during the build of the gitlab continuous integration. I have a javascript web application in nodejs and angularjs hosted on gitlab, with two repositories : one for the front and one for the back. For the front, I use a base image including node 7.7.1 and nginx and his configuration, hosted on an Amazon registry, and then the runner executes the npm install for the front, according to the package.json.

Here is the .gitlab-ci.yml :

```
image: docker:1.13.1

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

variables:
  BUILD_IMG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_BUILD_REF
  TEST_IMG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME
  RELEASE_IMG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
  AWS_STAGING_ENV: "argalisformation-prod-env"
  AWS_PROD_ENV: "argalisformation-prod-env"
  DOCKERRUN: Dockerrun.aws.json
  DEPLOY_ARCHIVE: ${AWS_APP}-${CI_BUILD_REF}.zip

before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN registry.gitlab.com
  - .ci/before_script

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - docker build --pull -t $BUILD_IMG .
  - docker push $BUILD_IMG

test:
  stage: test
  script:
  - docker pull $BUILD_IMG
  - docker run --rm $BUILD_IMG npm run test
  - docker tag $BUILD_IMG $TEST_IMG
  - docker push $TEST_IMG

deploy:staging:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Staging
  variables:
    DOCKER_IMG: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:${CI_BUILD_REF}
  script:
  - ./.ci/create-deploy-archive $DOCKER_IMG $AWS_BUCKET $DOCKERRUN $DEPLOY_ARCHIVE
  - ./.ci/aws-deploy $DEPLOY_ARCHIVE $CI_BUILD_REF $AWS_STAGING_ENV
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - $DEPLOY_ARCHIVE
  except:
  - production

deploy:production:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Production
  variables:
    DOCKER_IMG: ${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}:latest
  script:
  - .ci/push-new-image $TEST_IMG $RELEASE_IMG
  - .ci/create-deploy-archive $DOCKER_IMG $AWS_BUCKET $DOCKERRUN $DEPLOY_ARCHIVE
  - .ci/aws-deploy $DEPLOY_ARCHIVE $CI_BUILD_REF $AWS_PROD_ENV
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - $DEPLOY_ARCHIVE
  only:
  - production
  when: manual
```

Here is the output of the runner error :

```
npm info lifecycle node-sass@3.13.1~install: node-sass@3.13.1

> node-sass@3.13.1 install /src/node_modules/sasslint-webpack-plugin/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/install.js



The command '/bin/sh -c npm set progress=false && npm install node-sass --save-dev && npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

My npm version is 4.1.2.

Comment: So I understand the issue occurs during the `build` stage and the `docker build --pull -t $BUILD_IMG .` command? If so, please also share your `Dockerfile`